# Expectations and Probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $f(x)$ is a random polynomial that satisfies a certain property P with probability 1. Does $\mathbb{E}[f(x)]$ necessarily satisfy the property P? For instance, take $X$ and $Y$ to be i.i.d. with mean $\mu$. The polynomial $f(x)=(x-X)(x-Y)$ almost surely has real roots. The polynomial
$\mathbb{E}[f(x)]=(x-\mu)^2$ also has real roots. Does this hold in general? Or can somebody think of a counterexample? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $X$ is not zero almost surely. $E(X-\mu)=0$

Comment: $X_n\to X$ a.s. But $E X_n \not \to EX$

Answer (score 1):

No, this doesn't hold in general.  Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. with $\mathbb{P}(X=2)=\mathbb{P}(X=-2)=\frac 12$ and define $f(x) = x^2+XYx+1$.  Since $x^2+4x+1$ and $x^2-4x+1$ have real roots, $f$ always has real roots, but $\mathbb{E}[f(x)] = x^2+1$ does not have real roots.